# graphql-yoga - where are GraphQL resolver arguments defined and documented?

Tags: graphql, prisma

I've seen several sources describe the (root, args, context, info) arguments to a `graphql-yoga` resolver, but I am still searching for the real documentation of a `graphql-yoga` resolver. There are a few blog posts that mention the resolver arguments:

1. [prisma blog - Feb 2017 - *GraphQL Schemas, TypeDefs & Resolvers Explained*](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-the-schema-ac5e2950214e#9d03)
2. [prisma blog - Feb 2018 - *Demystifying the info Argument in GraphQL Resolvers*](https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-server-basics-demystifying-the-info-argument-in-graphql-resolvers-6f26249f613a/)

I know that `prisma` has built `graphql-yoga` on `graphql.js` via `graphql-tools`, and it appears that `graphql.js` [documents these parameters at graphql.org - Root fields & resolvers](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers), but it's not clear if `graphql.org` is the main place where `graphql.js` is documented, and even if it was, it is not clear to me that as a user of `graphql-yoga` I should defer to the documentation of `graphql.js`.

In addition, `prisma` has built `graphql-yoga` on `apollo-server`; is the documentation for `apollo-server` most applicable here?

It doesn't appear that these arguments are part of the GraphQL spec.

Where is the real documentation for the arguments to a `graphql-yoga` resolver? If that is not available and documented, where in the `graphql-yoga` source is the function that expects the arguments to take this shape?

Comment: Why the downvote? I have made a good faith effort to use stack overflow correctly with this question - please explain why you think this question is not a good fit. There's even a stack overflow meta question which affirms that well-written questions about documentation are on topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288008/are-questions-that-clairify-api-documentation-helpful-and-therefore-a-good-fit-f

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

For use with [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#overview), you probably want to follow [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server)'s docs for resolvers in the [`graphql-tools` section for `Resolver function signature`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Resolver-function-signature).

### Details

To know which docs to use, one needs to understand the full tech stack: [prisma](https://prisma.io) built stuff on top of tools by [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/), which in turn is built on top of the reference implementation of GraphQL, [graphql.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/graphs/contributors). Each layer of this stack has a separate docs site.

You can follow the trail from the [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#overview) README, which says it is built on [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server), whose own README in turn says:

> Apollo Server works with any GraphQL schema built with [GraphQL.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js), so you can build your schema with that directly or with a convenience library such as [graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/).

So [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#overview) is an opinionated, batteries-included form of [apollo-server](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server), which takes schemas from [graphql.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) but is likely to have more seamless integration with schemas specified with [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/)'s own [graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/).

Comment: I really, really wish the yoga docs were more explicit about that.  They should at least say "for how resolvers work, see the apollo docs".  Maybe I will drop them a note about that

Comment: The linked documentation can now be found at https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/resolvers#resolver-function-signature